# Web service that queries Broker Database outside of SDL Web 8.5?

Tags: content-delivery, web8.5, broker, odata, brokerquery

I know that there exists an API to query the Broker Database within the web application runtime of Web 8.5. I'm curious if there is an API that exists for a simple app that I'm trying to write for reporting purposes. Basically I need to map a metadata field from a Page with it's corresponding URL. Can anyone give me direction for how I can accomplish this without having access to the Broker Database API within a web server runtime? Thanks!

Comment: You need to connect to Content svc via CIL. https://shahideqamuddin.blogspot.com/2017/11/getting-started-with-tridion-cil.html or https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/b/blog-posts/posts/getting-started-with-content-interaction-library-cil-in-web-8-it-39-s-really-quite-simple

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You need to connect to Content svc via CIL. Here are a couple links:

https://shahideqamuddin.blogspot.com/2017/11/getting-started-with-tridion-cil.html

https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/b/blog-posts/posts/getting-started-with-content-interaction-library-cil-in-web-8-it-39-s-really-quite-simple